# When I build UI product on QT (using libcurl), reference to `inflateEnd'

Tags: linux, qt, gcc, libcurl

I build my UI product on raspberry Pi(using QT, and OS is ubuntu 20.04), the product using libuuid, libsqlite3, libcurl.
If I build without libcurl, it's make success, bud when I build include libcurl, the error is

```
./lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'.
```

I use other product test the libcurl(only using gcc command to build), the library is ok, make success.

So, how can I fix that?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Seems you're missing `-lz` in you link step.